# Need help to deploy Java web application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Hi I'm totally new to development. I'm trying deploy a web application on a local server like glassfish/tomcat. Backend of the app is written in Java and ui is created using HTML/css/js . I'm using maven as well. I'm not able to find a way to get this running on intellij CE .
Apparently this functionality is not supported in CE. Can someone suggest a turnaround or a different IDE as good as intellij idea. I've tried eclipse but I didn't find it completely useful

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "using git" since when can you deploy something with git? anyway take a look at this [Configuring Web Application Deployment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-web-application-deployment.html) (I guess it's only for the ultimate edition, not the CE)

Comment: Your questions though looks like more related to configuring to push code to remote repo,As a side note,use spring boot web apps as they remove the pain of explicitly deploying.

Comment: IntelliJ does let you use git from within the IDE. However the free version doesn't support web development.

Comment: Edited the question. Can someone suggest a turnaround as good as intellij ultimate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no* IDE as good as IntelliJ.  JetBrains makes the best IDEs on the market.

No, I don't work for them.  I have no affiliation at all.  I'm just a satisfied customer for the past 13 years who is happy to buy a license with my own money every year.

The [comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) for community and ultimate editions makes it clear: You *cannot* deploy in IntelliJ without a licensed copy.

You can create a WAR file and deploy it manually to Tomcat or Glassfish if you wish.  Why not just do that?

I will compliment you on how you are approaching the problem.  IntelliJ, Maven, and your other choices are very good.

If you feel up to the challenge, you can look into Spring Boot.  You can run an executable JAR and leave Java EE app servers behind.  IntelliJ community can easily run a Spring Boot app.

Choosing Spring Boot does mean leaving EJBs behind.  Everything you can do with Java EE is available in Spring Boot.  You'll be using POJOs.